# Firebase Hosting Custom Domain - site not "Go Live" after update DNS records by "CNAME records" method

Tags: dns, firebase, firebase-hosting

My domain verification process is completed and i also update my domain's DNS records to point to Firebase using "CNAME records" method (**updated before approx 96 hours**) but my site was not "Go Live". In Firebase console Hosting menu that give me below message:

> Your site will go live when your domain registrar propagates your updated records.

I have already deploy my site default index.html using "Firebase deploy" CLI command and it's already successfully uploaded on "mydomainname.firebaseapp.com"

My Question: why my custom domain is not redirect to Firebase hosting?

**Note**: I have set default GoDaddy DNS nameservers in my domain.

Comment: Make sure your DNS changes are correct, and that they've propagated. If you're certain of those, it might be time to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/).

Comment: Ya @FrankvanPuffelen, i have set CNAME records as per Firebase console but still same message are popup.(And Thanks for everything.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem and here is how i resolved it :

I put three parameters in the DNS record :

1. CNAME with www
2. A with 1st IP
3. A with 2nd IP

and then i only add two nameservers i.e.: ns1 & ns2 out of the 4 default Nameservers provided by name.com

and now my website is live on firebase.

-extra info:

it was not going live when i was using the 4 default nameservers.
it was not working with only one CNAME or both CNAME, or only both A with IP

I even contacted support on name.com they answered it is essential to have NameServer.

Comment: How did you add ns1 and ns2? What does it look like?

Comment: Ns1 and ns2 are the default ones in my case is:  ns1.name.com ns2.name.com, in another word just leave the default one provided by domain manager

Comment: Thanks, I asked Firebase Support and ended up resolving it by adding in Firebase A records IP address.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using GoDaddy

Just try changing your host name from 'customdomain.com' to '@'

That worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I could never get the "recommended" CNAME record to work.  I ended up just using the two IP's for the A record.  It took about 5 minutes to propagate enough to get my site in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are customizing your url domian with Godaddy and Firebase, you need to do the following:

- Remove your existing A record (domains from Godaddy has one A record by default).
- Add the A records from the instructions found in your Firebase Console.
- If you want to use www.yourdomain.com, you need to set up the subdomain in Godaddy Domain (Attached image).
- Maybe this step is not necesary, but I also added CNAME found in my Firebase Console.

After this changes you need to wait a few hours. If you problem persists Firebase has an excellent support as @FrankvanPuffelen says above. They solved my problems fastly.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me after adding those 3, that @Orkun Ozen and @SarkawtNoori mentioned:

1. CNAME with www
2. A with 1st IP
3. A with 2nd IP
   (without touching the nameservers)
   in the domain service site (in my case hostinger).

I added a new domain to Firebase and called it www.mydomain.com including to mydomain.com and it worked perfectly.... (though I had to wait for it to be secure).

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the custom firebase hosting site and added it again, actually when I did that it automatically was set as "connected". I didn't need to set up verification records or wait for provisioning.

Comment: @frank i have added a domain from godaddy in firebase. As domain id added and website is live. But most of the time is going down. And showing me godaddy page and showing that domain is parked free on godaddy. Please provide a solution for this.